# Should both nvidia and nouveau drivers be installed for GPU passthrough

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, drivers, nvidia, gpu

I'm following [an excellent tutorial](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/3lno0t/gpu_passthrough_revisited_an_updated_guide_on_how/) on passing GPU to a virtual machine. My system's output of `lspci -nnk` differs from the OP's - my kernel has only `nouveau` module but OP has both `nouveau` and `nvidia` installed.

I wonder, what impact does this fact have on host and guest machines?

Output of my `lspci`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 950] [10de:1402] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:3208]
Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
Kernel modules: nouveau
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter, because you are not going to use them on the host anyways. Since you are passing the device into a VM, the host must not use it and your lspci output tells me that you correctly load the stub driver (`vfio-pci`) instead of nvidia/nouveau. One of the stub drivers main jobs is to prevent either driver from claiming the device and trying to install `nvidia` now might actually mess up your stub driver loading.

Comment: Great - I thought it was so.